# How to install libvips with mozjpeg and libimagequant on Debian/Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, debian, vips, mozjpeg

I want to build a server for treat all images of a website.

I have a script in Nodejs using Sharp and I would like to setup the server with the best libs to use maximum power of libvips.

I would like to get help to install it.

I can install libvips-dev using:

```
apt-get install libvips-dev
```

But it don't have mozjpeg and libimagequant.

Answer (score 2):

To install `libimagequant` through `apt` you should have debian [(Buster, Bullseye or Sid)](https://packages.debian.org/buster/libimagequant-dev).

On Ubuntu the package is available only for [Ubuntu disco 19.04 and eoan 19.10](https://packages.ubuntu.com/disco/libimagequant-dev).

```
sudo apt install libimagequant-dev
```

The package `mozjpeg` is available on [this git repository](https://github.com/mozilla/mozjpeg), the build instruction and requirement : [building.md](https://github.com/mozilla/mozjpeg/blob/master/BUILDING.md)

Comment: How can I install it in ubuntu 16.04? Can't find the apt-get package for it on ubuntu 16.04

Comment: You can download the libimagequant source from https://github.com/ImageOptim/libimagequant/releases and then compile it using the instructions at https://github.com/ImageOptim/libimagequant#compiling-and-linking